# bitbucket git push error: pack-objects died of signal 127

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-tag

I receive the following error when I try to push my local changes to the remote git repository. Also, I couldn't find documentation on the signal number. I'm wondering whether it is a Bitbucket error rather than a git error. I tried to increase the buffer size but that didn't work. Also, I tried to create a new repository and push the entire code base to the new repository, but I receive the same error. Any suggestions on how to fix this is welcomed.

```
git push -u origin master
Password for 'https://myusername@bitbucket.org':
Counting objects: 52, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (48/48), done.
Writing objects: 100% (52/52), 36.13 MiB | 8.82 MiB/s, done.
Total 52 (delta 5), reused 0 (delta 0)
error: pack-objects died of signal 127
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
error: failed to push some refs to
'https://myusername@bitbucket.org/myusername/scheduler.git'
```

Comment: There's a misleading error message here: your Git is informing you that their Git said that their `pack-objects` failed. It's claiming that their pack-objects failed with "signal 127", which is wrong: there is no signal 127. But it is clear that their pack-objects is failing. What's not clear to me is *why* their pack-objects is dying, but only Bitbucket support can answer that.

Comment: @torek thanks for the reply. I will contact them directly. I was thinking it may be something Bitbucket specific